# How to open another cmd terminal via jenkins service

Tags: jenkins, cmd, jenkins-pipeline

I want to open another cmd terminal GUI via jenkins service, but I dont know how to do it.

in **test.bat** file, this file will run hello.bat in another cmd terminal

```
echo "testing ..."
start /min cmd /c hello.bat
```

in **hello.bat** file

```
echo "I see you 1"
echo "I see you 2"
echo "I see you 3"
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 8 > nul
```

I run test.bat manually and it works as expected, it trigger the test.bat in another cmd terminal.

[image]

But when I try to run **test.bat** from jenkins, I cannot see another cmd terminal GUI that running **hello.bat**

Below is the screenshot to prove it is running successful
[image]

but there is no another cmd terminal GUI is pop up during jenkins run in the jenkins agent PC
[image]

Below is my jenkins service setting, I tested with both Log on option, one is logon as user account, one as "Local System account" and tick the "allow service to interreact with desktop", both fail the expectation.
[image]

Please guide me on this issue, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Start a program` build step in Jenkins and specify `cmd.exe` as the program to run.
Or you can use the `bat` step and specify `cmd.exe` as the command to run if you are using Jenkins pipelines as below:

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage('Open Command Prompt') {
            steps {
                bat 'cmd.exe'
                bat 'echo Hello from the new command prompt window!'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you can read more about the bat command here:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#bat-execute-windows-batch-command